# Is there a way to prevent new profiles being added on chrome windows using registry editor?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser, windows-registry

I went here `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` and created a Dword 32-bit value with the name `BrowserAddPersonEnabled` & value `1`.
This worked well but after I stopped Edge search suggestions on the Search Bar this is no longer working.

But they should not be affecting each other, they are in different registry hives.

Comment: Why are you expecting Google Chrome group policies to impact Microsoft Edge?  Microsoft Edge has it's own policies. Edge and Chrome use two different keys to be able or prevent a user profile from being generated.

Comment: Perhaps I don’t understand the connection between Edge search suggestions and Chrome. I don’t see how the two are even remotely connected

Comment: No, I am just writing down all the changes made so that an informed opinion/answer could be given that is all.

Comment: All what changes? I think you may be observing things and assuming they are related when they are not. Reset those changes and then change them again and see whether the same thing happens.